# Thread safe writing to file from two isolates in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, thread-safety, isolate

I have a Flutter app where there are two isolates, the main isolate and another isolate for background works.

Now, I write logs to the same file from both isolates. But, when both run concurrently, some partial texts are missed.